# Typescript TS2558 error and the meaning of keep<number>

Tags: typescript

I'm trying a typescript problem on exercism.com and see the test code as the following.

```
import {keep, discard} from './strain'

describe('strain', () => {
  it('keeps on empty array returns empty array', () => {
    expect(keep<number>([], (e: number) => e < 10)).toEqual([])
  })
```

I tried to write strain.ts as followed

```
 export function keep(list: number[], fn: Function): number[] {
```

but I got an error

```
strain.test.ts(5,12): error TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.
```

What does keep < number > () mean? And how do I solve TS2558 error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, they are trying to teach you the concept of [TypeScript generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). Please do read the documentation on them or try some blog posts on TypeScript generics basics.

---

I am not sure what exactly your **first question** is. If you're asking what `<number>` means, then you'll find the answer in the docs. In short, it's a *type argument*. It is being used with generic classes and generic methods/functions.

You can think of *Type argument* roughly as a placeholder for a type in a template function which will be inferred (sort of "guessed", simply speaking) when the generic class is being created or the generic function being called. I'm using very simple and not technically 100% correct terms here.

---

Your **second question** is about how to fix the problem. First, you need to understand that the current code of your function is not generic, because `function keep()` misses a type argument, and this is exactly what the error is telling you: *Hey, you're invoking `keep<number>(...)` as if it was a generic function with type `number`, but `keep` does not receive a type argument! I mean, there's no place to plug the `number` into!!*.

So, in order to fix it, you need to make the function generic by "providing a place to plug that type in". Look at this:

```
export function keep<T>(list: T[], fn: (x: T) => boolean): T[] {
  // your code goes here
  // this is what they want you to implement
}
```

Notice the signature:  it receives an array of `T`'s (by analogy with `string[]` as list of `string`s or `number[]` as list of `number`s). The specific type of `T` will be determined in each place where `keep()` is being called from.

For example, TypeScript compiler will understand that in the invocation `keep(["a", "b", "c"], text => text !== "b")`, `T` is actually the `string` type. Whereas, in `keep([1, 2, 3, 4], num => num % 2 === 0)`, `T` is a `number`.

Hope, you get the idea and you figure out yourself how to write the body of the function.

---

A few unrelated notes.

- Generics are very powerful tool for type checking and writing generalized code capable of working against various types. You absolutely need to grasp it *eventually*. Don't worry if you don't quite get every detail. This aspect has many tricky details.
- The type argument(s) can be more than one:

  ```
  function myFunction<T1, T2, T3>(t1: T1, t2: T2): T3 {
    // ...
  }
  ```
- The type argument(s) can have arbitrary names, not just "T":

  ```
  function myFunction<A, B>(a: A): B {
    // ...
  }
  ```
- There's much more to it! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for very detailed explanations. I still have a lot to learn about generics.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond don't worry. Things will come with experience!